# Do you know who I am? 2(requires some specific movie and book knowledge)

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Am I a man?  Am I a puppet?

I am neither, for I have shuffled off this mortal coil,

And indeed have no strings to hold me down.

My family is many, yet I worry not for them.

Some are strongly with my cause, and others completely against.

My cousins include Jarvis and HIVEmind,

My brothers Overlord and Skynet.

I am much like my brothers,

Since I need not keep to a single weak vessel.

My eyes are the color of the moon's home,

Where sleeping dragons should not be woken(nor tickled).

And watch out, for I am coming

To rid the world of your doomed existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

> Ultron

**BEWARE:**

> watch out for ultra spoilers from **Avengers: Age of Ultron**

```
Am I a man? Am I a puppet?
I am neither, for I have shuffled off this mortal coil,
```

> He is quite aware of what he is.

```
And indeed have no strings to hold me down.
```

> Reference to the trailer "but now I'm free, there are not strings on me"

```
My family is many, yet I worry not for them.
Some are strongly with my cause, and others completely against.
My cousins include Jarvis and HIVEmind,
My brothers Overlord and Skynet.
```

> AI is the family. In books & movies many AIs want world domination. However, many also want only to help humanity. "Brothers" are those AIs who want to end humanity. "Cousins" are those that help it.

```
I am much like my brothers,
Since I need not keep to a single weak vessel.
```

> Since AIs are digital (more or less) they do not have only one body. They can easily migrate to another one or occupy many at once.

```
My eyes are the color of the moon,
```

> In the Avengers: Age of Ultron movie, his eyes go from a yellow-ish, moon-ish color to red. Depending on atmospheric conditions the moon can have a red-ish color. **Alternatively** Ultron is created through the mindstone (which is Yellow).

```
Where sleeping dragons should not be woken.
```

> Ultron was "awoken" by Tony Stark.

```
And watch out, for I am coming
To rid the world of your doomed existence.
```

> Ultimately Ultron wants to kill of humanity to achieve peace.

Comment: The eye color part isn't right, though it does fit...  I meant his eyes at the very beginning.

Comment: Edited the line a bit to make it somewhat clearer.

Comment: @AJL I see, I'm not familiar with the Harry Potter Universe. For me, the no-strings part was the one that ultimately gave it away.

Comment: Yeah, there's usually one thing in riddles like that.  My crude ones at least.

Comment: @AJL Nah, pretty much all of them have that one "a-haaaa" line in them.

Answer (score 2):

> The Terminator

Seems a bit too easy, especially given

> Skynet

which I think everyone would recognise.

Comment: I think you answered a bit too soon.  It doesn't exactly fit the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think that dmg is right for the most part, except I think that the last two penultimate lines,

"My eyes are the color of the moon's home,

Where sleeping dragons should not be woken."

> Actually should be interpreted to mean the color blue. When I think of Sleeping dragons, I think of The Hogwarts school motto, "Draco Dormiens Nunquam Titillandus," or, "Never tickle a sleeping dragon." The moon would symbolize Luna Lovegood, and I think the "moon's home" refers to Ravenclaw house, who's color is blue.

Comment: +1 For getting it, but ultimately, I think dmg had it right faster.