# Our life and death are one, we two

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Hair the color of rose's imperfection

Eyes like the one who is part of me,

Though we are two.

And the other of us is the color

Of his fallen relatives in the

Safest place on the earth(besides _________)

My family and I are celebrimbor,

But we are just my two brothers and me.

For now.

---

**Mainly only one book, with two other references.  Who are the two, the brothers and what does the ____ part mean?**

Spoiler

> Dragons!

More hints...

> I am not that which you call by my name, for that person belongs to a more modernly created world than I live in.

Comment: Ha - looks like we both posted riddles with (at least slightly) similar themes almost simultaneously! :-)

Comment: Are you Saphira by any chance?

Comment: You are so close...  Right story, but Saphira has no hair...

Comment: **[Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24004/chat-about-sci-fi-and-fantasy-adventure-puzzles) for puzzles of this type.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* it's

> Arya, from the *Inheritance* cycle of fantasy novels.

For the rest of it, SPOILER ALERTS!

*Our life and death are one, we two*

> That's her and Firnen, her dragon. The bond between Rider and dragon is one of my favourite parts of those books.

*Hair the color of rose's imperfection*

> She has black hair, and blackleg is a plant disease affecting roses.

*Eyes like the one who is part of me,*

> She has green eyes, and Firnen is green.

*Though we are two.*

> Two in body, but one in mind and spirit.

*And the other of us is the color*

*Of his fallen relatives in the*

*Safest place on the earth(besides _________)*

> Firnen's relatives (other dragon eggs and Eldunari) are hidden away in the Vault of Souls at Vroengard, perhaps the safest place in the world besides the elven forest.

*My family and I are celebrimbor,*

> This refers to family not in the literal sense but in the sense of dragon Riders. Celebrimbor was an elven lord in LotR whose name means "silver hand", as in *Argetlam* - dragon Riders all have silver on their hands from the *gedwey ignasia*.

*But we are just my two brothers and me.*

> The only dragon Riders in existence are Eragon, Murtagh, and Arya ...

*For now.*

> ... but more will hopefully arrive when the other eggs hatch.

The first hint is now self-explanatory. For the second:

> Not to be confused with Arya Stark, a character of the same name in a more recently written fantasy novel ("more modernly created world").

Comment: Ummm...  Basically, who has a male dragon and use the clues to figure out which it is.  BTW, do you know what Celebrimbor means?

Comment: Note that celebrimbor has a meaning and is lowercase.  Safest place on the earth is related to a different book.

Comment: @AJL OK, I've now solved all of it except the "safest place on the earth" - could it be the caves of Ulgoland from the Belgariad/Malloreon?

Comment: Also the hair thing.  Maybe I should change it to rose bush's imperfection?

Comment: And what color is the dragon?  Who are the dragon's fallen relatives?  That may help.

Comment: Never would've found it (even though I kinda like these trivia riddles). My memory decided to flush everything after the first book, but thats just personal taste :P   It's an awesome find (the answer) and a nice riddle :)  +1s to both of you

Comment: @AJL He's green (which is the stereotypical dragon colour), but I can't remember what colour the Belgariad/Malloreon dragon(s) are. Any chance of another hint?

Comment: Fallen relatives, literally...  Not LotR

Comment: @randal'thor HP(are you familiar with the acronym?) is part of the fallen relatives etc. clue

Comment: @AJL [This](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Common_Welsh_Green)?

Comment: It's not really that specific...  The first thing I went to for green in the HP universe would be ____

The imperfection on a rosebush happens to be a character's name, and the character(not a human:)) is black.

Comment: @AJL Green in HP - the first thing that comes to my mind is the main character's eyes. "the character(not a human:)) is black" - is this in HP or Inheritance?

Comment: True about HP, but take a look at http://www.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/do-you-know-who-i-am-2requires-some-specific-movie-and-book-knowledge for the color of something.  I tend to think of using those specific things for colors(the right four, anyways)

The second is in Inheritance.